# Pyautogui - How to type random words or numbers ("error: object not iterable")?

Tags: python, typeerror, iterable, pyautogui

I'm quite new to python. I want pyautogui to type a random number or word. I've tried it like this:

```
a = random.randint(1,10)
pyautogui.typewrite(a)
```

but it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Doesn't pyautogui support variables, or do I have to use another formatting?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`pyautogui.typewrite` accepts a string as its parameter. So if you cast the number (int) to a string it should print out fine:

```
a = random.randint(1,10)
pyautogui.typewrite(str(a))
```